# Gridview BoundField Remove Time from DateTime In Edit/Update Mode

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview, edit, boundfield

I have the following GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
    DataKeyNames="EVENT,TERM_CODE" DataSourceID="OracleDataSource" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
    EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EVENT" HeaderText="Event" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="EVENT" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TERM_CODE" HeaderText="Term Code" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="TERM_CODE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SNAPSHOT_DATA_DATE" HeaderText="Snapshot Date" 
            SortExpression="SNAPSHOT_DATA_DATE" DataFormatString="{0:d}"  />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The SNAPSHOT_DATA_DATE column is a DateTime field in the database.
I only want to show the date not both the date and time ex. 7/25/2012
So I added `DateFormatString="{0:d}"` to the BoundField and this works great when viewing the Gridview. However, if I click the edit link to update the date it displays as: 7/25/2012 12:00:00 AM The DateFormatString is ignored in edit mode. Can someone  please tell me how to remove the time when in edit / update mode? I don't want users dealing with the time only the date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you have set the following properties for formatting to work in Edit Mode in Bound field.

```
DataFormatString = ({0:d})
ApplyFormatInEditMode = True
```

In your code if you just modify like below, it should work fine

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="SNAPSHOT_DATA_DATE" HeaderText="Snapshot Date" ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" SortExpression="SNAPSHOT_DATA_DATE" DataFormatString="{0:d}"  />
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  I didn't know about the ApplyFormatInEditMode tag.
Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have converted your boundfield to a template column, the "ApplyFormatInEditMode" property is not available on a template field. You can get rid of the time in the bound text box by then using <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MeetingDate", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 2):

I specifically wanted to format my date as `yyyy/MM/dd` without the time equivalent to the following:

```
string dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

To do this I just added the format on the `DataFormatString` attribute for the BoundField:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DatePosted" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" />
```